# What is the difference between the below two declarations?

Tags: javascript

What is the difference between the below two declarations ?

This

```
var person={firstname:"John",lastname:"Doe",id:3423};
```

and this

```
var person=new Object();
person.firstname="John";
person.lastname="Doe";
person.id=3423;
```

So person is a variable or object ?

Comment: `So person is a variable or object?` -- Yes.

Comment: there might be a small difference : first one might be faster, depending on how smart the javascript engine is. (a totally smart compiler would have both time the same). Because with the second way 1) we create 3 properties one by one, and 2) checks have to be done each time that such attribution is allowed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With respect to the resulting object, there'll be no difference in outcome between the two approaches. They both create a plain object with `Object.prototype` in their prototype chain, and the properties you've defined will be directly on the object.

In both cases, `person` is a variable that holds a reference to an object.